# Upgrading interrupted and apt-get got broken, how to fix it?

Tags: 14.04, boot, apt, 16.04, upgrade

I was upgrading from 14.04.5 to 16.04 using the Software Updater on my laptop. After I closed the lid and trigered the system to suspend during the downloaded packages were installing, it didn't go to the sleep mode. So, I opened the lid only to found the screen went to black with date and a "root" label on the top bar. Clicking mouse or pressing any button did nothing but give a flash on the screen. I thought maybe this is just because the upgrading was going on, and left the computer on for a day and left for work. When I came back to my laptop and find the screen was where I left and no response to any button press. So, I went to the TTY mode and found there were broken things (I don't remember what's on the screen). I tried typed in `sudo apt-get update`, and it returned with some message showing `apt-get` was broken (maybe also told me some soft links cannot found as well). I turned off the computer and restarted it, and it couldn't go to the login screen any more. `systemd status systemd-modules-load.service` showed there were errors on loading core modules, and the system gave up on booting into Ubuntu. The `apt` module couldn't be loaded by `update-notifier/apt-check` and `python3` or something.

Could anyone shadow a light on me to help fix this problem? I don't have my files backed up because of lack of spare disks, and thought it wouldn't have any problem to upgrade from one LTS to another. But this happened, and made the Ubuntu system completely unuseable. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your files in the same partition in which Ubuntu is installed or in some different partition ?

Comment: Only one disk, but `/`, `/boot` and `/home` are separated. Also dual boots with Windows 10.

Comment: If you need access to your files, and do not succeed in fixing your install, you'll be able to access them by booting off the Ubuntu installation media and accessing (and potentially backing them up) from there.

Comment: Anything I can try to fix the `apt-get` error? I am thinking to avoid a fresh installation in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Can I boot into USB live and then use chroot to continue the upgrade?